# Cant get intents working with a Spinner

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, spinner, android-spinner

I am trying to replace the toasts in the code below with intents, but no matter how many methods i try they fail to work. The issue is nothing but a white screen on the emulator when loading up the application.
Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
    {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (arg2) {
            case 0:                 
                Toast.makeText(UsefulToolsActivity.this, "Tool, Countdown. Selected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case 1:                 
                Toast.makeText(UsefulToolsActivity.this, "Tool, Countdown. Selected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                       
                break;

            default :                       
                break;
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the code i tried using to implement the intents

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (arg2) {
            case 0:                 
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(UsefulToolsActivity.this, CountdownActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);                        
                break;

            case 1:                 
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(UsefulToolsActivity.this, CountdownActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent2);                       
                break;

            default :                       
                break;
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
```

Logcat output on application execution

```
    12-23 13:45:50.637: E/JavaBinder(621): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
    12-23 13:45:50.957: E/AndroidRuntime(621): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-23 13:45:50.957: E/AndroidRuntime(621): java.lang.RuntimeException: Adding window failed
    12-23 13:45:50.957: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:491)
    12-23 13:45:50.957: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:301)
    12-23 13:45:50.957: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
    12-23 13:45:50.957: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
    12-23 13:45:50.957: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
    12-23 13:45:50.957: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2507)
    12-23 13:45:50.957: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1986)
    12-23 13:45:50.957: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
    12-23 13:45:50.957: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
    12-23 13:45:50.957: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    12-23 13:45:50.957: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    12-23 13:45:50.957: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    12-23 13:45:50.957: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-23 13:45:50.957: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    12-23 13:45:50.957: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    12-23 13:45:50.957: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    12-23 13:45:50.957: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    12-23 13:45:50.957: E/AndroidRuntime(621): Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
    12-23 13:45:50.957: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
    12-23 13:45:50.957: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.add(IWindowSession.java:516)
    12-23 13:45:50.957: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:481)
    12-23 13:45:50.957: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  ... 16 more
```

Comment: Are the toasts shown? Have you checked if onItemSelected is called?

Comment: and how do you use intents ? Show your code.

Comment: Provide a little more code and generated error if any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer after experimenting a lot, and it ended up being i had forgotten to implement OnItemSelectedListener.

Answer (score 0):

getIntent() will work for spinner if both your arguments for ne Inent() are equal.. Otherwise it will not.